# grep filename[asterisk] returns unexpected result

Tags: regex, shell, grep, glob

I have a basic question about `ls` command.
Suppose in a directory I have 4 files named

```
run
run1
running
run.sh
```

So, if i do: `ls -l|grep run*` then I get no result.

But if i do `ls -l|grep run.*` then I get `run.sh` as a result.

However I expected `grep` to list all of the files in both the cases.
Could you make me understand what is going on behind scenes?

Comment: grep stands for `global regular expressions print` not `global wildcard print`. `run*` is wildcard syntax; `run.*` is regex syntax.

Comment: Also note that parsing ls is not recommended. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs .

Comment: I think that grepping the output of ls is still permitted, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as I understand, the "*" is expanded by the shell before executing the command itself, so your grep will try to catch a string with all the file names! On the other hand, grep expects a regular expression, so the "*" is not interpreted as you expect.

The direct solution would be:

```
$ ls -l run*
```

Or, if you want to use grep, then scape the "*" and provide a regular expression:

```
$ ls -l|grep run.\*
$ ls -l|grep 'run.*'
```

Comment: Oh yes, exactly. I wish i could vote you up. Sadly it needs 15 reputation atleast :( . Thanks a lot.

Comment: If any of the answers has helped you solving your problem, you should mark one of them as an accepted answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

This is because the asterisk is special to the shell and gets expanded. To avoid this, you have to quote the regex for grep to see it unexpanded:

```
ls -l|grep 'run*'
```

And note that this is not what you want, because 'run*' as an regexp means 'ru followed by any number of `n`'. This will list also files named `rubber` and so on. To list files that match a **shell glob pattern** (which is different from an regexp), why not simply use

```
ls -l run*
ls -l run.*
```

and avoid the useless grep process entirely?

Comment: Well definitely this is not what i want but now i am more confused. Because what you say seems right then what if i write ls run*? why does it return all the four filenames here?

Comment: Exactly! "ls run\*" would be equivalent to "ls run run1 running run.sh"

Comment: well my main which i didnt express in the question is to list down all files irrespective of its case. Somthing like `ls -l|grep -i <filename>`. since ls doesnt server the purpose i had to go this way.

Answer (score 1):

Before the shell even runs `grep`, it searches through your command for any unquoted file globbing characters, and performs filename expansion on those arguments.

So when you enter this command:

```
ls -l | grep run*
```

the shell uses the pattern `run*` to search for files in the current directory, and finds `run`, `run1`, `running` and `run.sh`. It then rewrites the `grep` command with those arguments:

```
ls -l | grep run run1 running run.sh
```

which causes `grep` to search `run1`, `running` and `run.sh` for the string `run`.

As noted, the solution is to quote the argument to `grep` so the shell does not try to perform filename expansion on it:

```
ls -l | grep 'run.*'
```

Comment: indeed. The explanation about expansion answers my second question. But anyways `ls -l | grep run*`  should have thrown a message saying `grep:No match`   which it throws if you write `ls -l | grep runnnnn*`

Comment: Not at all. See my answer: you have four files in this directory whose names begin with `run`, so `run*` expands to all four `run run1 running run.sh`. But there are no filenames that match `runnnnn*`, which is why the shell throws that error. I am not sure where the confusion originates here.

Comment: Let me ask it this way: `ls -l|grep run*` doesnt yield any result then why does it not throw any error message. On the other hand `ls -l|grep runnnn*` also doesnt yield any result but an errro message is shown as grep:No match. What causes grep not to throw the message in first case?

Comment: +1: This is the best answer so far; it explains what went wrong. None of the three files `run1`, `running` or `run.sh` actually contains the word `run`, so you get no output from the `ls -l | grep run*` command. In fact, the `ls -l` output is completely ignored by `grep`; it only reads its standard input when there are no file name arguments, or when one of those arguments is `-` (dash, all on its own) or one of the names such as `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd/0` that is a synonym for standard input.

Comment: @user3083195 I see the confusion now. The `No match` message is actually issued by the shell when it finds no filenames that match your glob pattern. The shell prints `grep: No match` to indicate that you tried to run `grep` with a filename pattern but that filename pattern did not produce any filenames to run on, so the shell did not actually run `grep` at all. When `grep` searches a file and does not find any matches to your regex, it will just quietly print no output and will not produce any error message. Does that help explain the difference?

Comment: If this answer helped you understand what's going on, please consider marking it "accepted" :-)